# How to change CommandBar Title font size in Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have created a Xamarin.Forms application and it *has quite a long name.*
When I start it on my 4.5" Windows 10 phone, it looks very strange.

The main page consists of a `TabbedPage` and it has the `Title` property, however it has no `FontSize`property.

[image]

I use the following `Style` in my PCL project:

```
 <Style TargetType="Label">     
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource BaseColor}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="18"
                         Tablet="28" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

However, if I remove it, the title is still very large.

Where can I modify the title font size to make the title *smaller*?

**UPDATE**:

I checked with the Live Property Editor, and it shows that the `Title` is inside the `CommandBar` and the `FontSize` is set to 24.

[image]

I tried to override its style (both in XAML and in code), but it doesn't work:

```
 <forms:WindowsPage.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CommandBar">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="4" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Whatever" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CommandBar.Style>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Whatever" />
            </CommandBar.Content>
        </CommandBar>
    </forms:WindowsPage.BottomAppBar>



 public MainPage()
 {
  this.InitializeComponent();
  var bapp = BottomAppBar;
  LoadApplication(new MyXamarinApp.App(IoC.Get<SimpleContainer>()));
  BottomAppBar = bapp;
  BottomAppBar.FontSize = 4;
 }
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE 2:**

You can download a sample project from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8aAkabXOq4vU3JkRjN2N1J5S2M).

Comment: Could you share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Sure, it is easily reproducible. I added a link to the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ***override one of the built-in styles:***

```
 <!-- Tab title  -->
 <Style x:Key="TitleTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
 </Style>
```